# Showing <button> as button

Tags: discussion, design, editor

In many questions or answers users say about some buttons like `search` button, `Ok` button and so on, We also have `<kbd />` tag to show keyboard keys as a <kbd>key</kbd>. Well, I can show a button as a <kbd>key button</kbd> but I think `<kbd />` is just for keyboard keys, And at the end I think it can make sense to use a special tag to show a button as **<kbd>button</kbd>**.

I can suggest `<btn />` tag with a style similar to nav-bar buttons of site like `nav-questions` or a style like `Search` button at search page with hover if it is inside a link.

Comment: The last thing we need is more over-formatting of text in posts. We already get people who `use code formatting for emphasis` Or **bold** words which **do** not need **to** be bolded. Adding button formatting on top of keyboard formatting just gets obnoxious and make the post hard to read.

Answer (score 6):

The standard says that `kbd` can be used to represent [any form of user input](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) and that a `kbd` nested in another `kbd` represents a single key. But `b` [works just as well](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) for representing button labels and you can use that as an alternative since the current site stylesheet treats top-level `kbd` elements as representing single keys (or just not format them at all; the post is no less readable without formatting button labels).

As mentioned, `button` is an actual interface/form element that you interact with and it would be inappropriate to use in that context. Unless you're trying to use it to make a link to a fiddle or some other off-site demo stand out, in which case just use a regular hyperlink. Seriously. It does not need to stand out.

Comment: In some edits I saw, some top-users remove `<kbd />` with commenting the edit by **Use keyboard tag for keyboard keys only**! ;).

Answer (score 3):

`<button>` is [an actual HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) that's intended to be clicked on/interacted with. I don't know off-hand if we actually use that in our code (I think it's mostly `<input>`, but don't quote me on that), but we *could* and for that reason I hesitate to recommend special styling for dummy buttons in actual posts.

As far as referring to buttons in posts goes, I think that if the visuals really make a difference there, then taking a screenshot of whatever website or software is being described is likely the best way to go vs any of our own styling.

Comment: In an answer like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4221219/4519059) for `Format Options` or in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10656067/4519059) ;).